# Why am I receiving with this AJAX script the status 404?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I got into AJAX and am using the MAMP web server and trying to implement a simple script which should show me whether this is working. I tried tracking down the problem by using the status property of XMLHttpRequest();
I found out that it was a problem of type 404 (Page not found) and this is astonishing as I am using JSON file to handle the script which is in the same directory as my ajax script.

Here is the AJAX script:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {

if (xhr.status === 200) {

    alert("Good");
}

else if(xhr.status === 304)
{
    alert("304");

}


else if(xhr.status === 404)
{
    alert("404");
} 

else
{
    alert("500");
}
xhr.open("GET", 'json.json', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

And here my file json.json:

```
{
"events" :
[
    {
        "location" : "San Francisco, CA"
    }

]
}
```

This is really frustrating. Thanks in advance,

Raul Rao

Comment: The fact it is returning 404 means it cannot find your 'json.json' file. Use the Network tab in your browsers Developer Tools to see the full URL that is being requested.

Comment: Is the json.json file in the same folder as the page executing the script?

Comment: Yes, he JSOn file is in the same folder.

Comment: You said in your response to the comment above "the JSON file is in the **same folder [as the page executing the script]**." But in your question, you said "JSON file to handle the script which is in the **same directory as my ajax script**". Those are two different things. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using JSON file to handle the script which is in the same directory as my ajax script

The location of the json file has nothing to do with the location of some JavaScript file. The server does not know or care where the JS file running on the front-end happened to be retrieved from, and has no way of finding anything relative to that. Instead, the Ajax URL is interpreted relative to the URL of the page being served (if specified as relative; it can also be specified as absolute, in which case it's relative to the web document root).

Examples that will work when retrieving `json.json` from `html.html`:

```
webroot
    html.html
    json.json       <== is at same level as html.html
    js
        js.js       <== doesn't matter where this is

webroot
    html
        html.html
        json.json   <== is at same level as html.html
    js
        js.js
```

Examples that **won't** work:

```
webroot
    html.html
    js
        js.js       <== doesn't matter where this is
        json.json   <== is not at same level as html.html
```

Examples that **will** work when retrieving `/json.json` (note the leading slash):

```
webroot
    html
        html.html
    json.json       <== at web root
    js
        js.js
```

Comment: Actually I think it might be better to mention it should be in the same folder as the page that _executes_ the script but otherwise, yeah.

Comment: Sry but what do you mean with "root of a webserver", do you mean the htdocs because it is in that root directory and the JSON file is in the same folder as my ajax.js file. And this answer does not answer why I get Status 404.

Comment: Because 404 means "not found". Yes, by root I meant htdocs. Noone knows or cares where the JS file came from when it is being executed. Ajax URLs are interpreted relative to the page being served.